# How to sort parent documents related on nested object in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

For example my documents looks something like:

```html
{
  name: "John Doe",
  orders: [
    {
      name: "Rice",
      created_at: "2021-08-05"
    },
    {
      name: "Bread",
      created_at: "2021-08-12"
    },
    {
      name: "Butter",
      created_at: "2021-06-11"
    }
  ]
},
{
  name: "Jane Doe",
  orders: [
    {
      name: "Bread",
      created_at: "2020-07-10"
    }
  ]
},
{
  name: "John Smith",
  orders: [
    {
      name: "Eggs",
      created_at: "2021-08-15"
    },
    {
      name: "Bread",
      created_at: "2021-09-24"
    },
  ]
}
```

I what to sort parent documents by the "Bread" orders date (created_at)

In my example case the order of documents will be (asc):

1.Jane Doe

2.John Doe

3.John Smith

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to tell ElasticSearch to [sort on the nested field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sort-search-results.html#_nested_sorting_examples).

```
POST /_search
{
   "query" : {
      "match_all": {}
   },
   "sort": [
     {
       "orders.created_at": {
         "order": "asc",
         "nested": {
            "path": "orders",
            "filter": {
               "term" : { "orders.name" : "Bread" }
            }
         }
       }
     }
   ]
}
```

In this example, a n[ested sort filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sort-search-results.html#_nested_sorting_examples) is specified which tells ElasticSearch which `created_at` filed is to be used from the nested objects.